# How do I diagnose a failing nix build?

Tags: nix

How do I diagnose a nix build failing?

Currently I see output as:

```
nix build -v
warning: dumping very large path (> 256 MiB); this may run out of memory
building '/nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv'...
builder for '/nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv' failed with exit code 1; last 5 log lines:
  unpacking sources
  unpacking source archive /nix/store/s7r5vlvp49ad6a9d5hqhsiaxw691iyhf-Blog
  source root is Blog
  patching sources
  configuring
[0 built (1 failed), 0.0 MiB DL]
error: build of '/nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv' failed
```

I'd expect to find some logs / errors of why it failed to build?

---

Following from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264375/1663462:

I've tried adding   `build-cache-failures = true;` to the `default.nix` however I still see no output from:

```
nix-store --read-log
```

And `nix-store --query-failed-paths` results in:

```
error: no operation specified
Try 'nix-store --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading log should work.  Did you specify the derivation?  `nix-store --read-log /nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv`

Comment: If by that you mean `nix-store --read-log /nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv` then yes this seems to add additional info.

Comment: Sometimes it's also useful to build with `--keep-failed` to retain the temporary directory of the build.

Comment: Is this the same functionality that is implemented here https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/2810 with a new `--print-build-logs`?

Comment: What I posted reads logs of past builds.  What you link appears to be "only" about showing logs of the builds that are currently happening.

Comment: `nix log /nix/store/fdrm6kbm68vld3bhfjizv684ck725lyf-blog.drv`

Answer (score 7):

see also:

- [nix-build-debug](https://github.com/milahu/nix-build-debug) - debug failing nix-build in interactive bash shell
- [Building a stdenv package in nix-shell](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/stdenv/stdenv.chapter.md#building-a-stdenv-package-in-nix-shell-sec-building-stdenv-package-in-nix-shell) in the nixpkgs docs
- [Nix-build-phases: run nix build phases interactively](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-build-phases-run-nix-build-phases-interactively/36090) in the nixos discourse
- [Development environment with nix-shell](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell#stdenv.mkDerivation) in the nixos wiki
- [runPhase function in nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/817c314ea6911512f61a21cc0cf8296e3b085145/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh#L1527)

  - `eval "${!curPhase:-$curPhase}"`
  - `cd "${sourceRoot:-.}"`
- [genericBuild function in nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/817c314ea6911512f61a21cc0cf8296e3b085145/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh#L1565) - calls `runPhase $curPhase`

to debug the build process of a package:

instead of `nix-build`

```bash
nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./. {}'
```

run `nix-shell` to enter the build environment

```bash
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./. {}'
```

and then run the build phases

```bash
# run build in tempdir
cd $(mktemp -d)

# dont install to /nix/store
for n in $outputs; do eval export $n=$PWD/result-$n; done

# https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh
phases="${prePhases[*]:-} unpackPhase patchPhase ${preConfigurePhases[*]:-} \
    configurePhase ${preBuildPhases[*]:-} buildPhase checkPhase \
    ${preInstallPhases[*]:-} installPhase ${preFixupPhases[*]:-} fixupPhase installCheckPhase \
    ${preDistPhases[*]:-} distPhase ${postPhases[*]:-}";

echo writing nix-build-phases.txt
for curPhase in $phases; do
    echo "eval \"\${$curPhase:-$curPhase}\""
    if [ "$curPhase" = unpackPhase ]; then
        echo '[ -n "${sourceRoot:-}" ] && chmod +x "${sourceRoot}"'
        echo 'cd "${sourceRoot:-.}"'
    fi
done >nix-build-phases.txt

echo "please manually run the build phases in nix-build-phases.txt"
echo
cat nix-build-phases.txt
```

example nix-build-phases.txt

```
eval "${unpackPhase:-unpackPhase}"
[ -n "${sourceRoot:-}" ] && chmod +x "${sourceRoot}"
cd "${sourceRoot:-.}"
eval "${patchPhase:-patchPhase}"
eval "${updateAutotoolsGnuConfigScriptsPhase:-updateAutotoolsGnuConfigScriptsPhase}"
eval "${configurePhase:-configurePhase}"
eval "${buildPhase:-buildPhase}"
eval "${checkPhase:-checkPhase}"
eval "${installPhase:-installPhase}"
eval "${fixupPhase:-fixupPhase}"
eval "${installCheckPhase:-installCheckPhase}"
eval "${distPhase:-distPhase}"
```

in this build environment, you can

- find the cause of build errors (what build phase is failing?)
- modify the build commands, for example redefine the `buildPhase`: run `type buildPhase` to print the old phase, copy the old phase, modify the phase, paste the new phase
- run the modified build commands. this can be faster than a full rebuild

note: builders can execute different build phases. the actual build phases are stored in variables like `prePhases` or `preConfigurePhases`

problem: the build script runs with `set -e` so it will exit on the first error, but that would exit the interative shell. this is a limitation of the bash shell, so ideally, we would run the build script in a bash debugger, to stop execution on the first error, modify commands, step back and repeat execution of commands, and to allow inspection of state.

```bash
# run build in tempdir
cd $(mktemp -d)

# dont install to /nix/store
for n in $outputs; do eval export $n=$PWD/result-$n; done

# https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh
phases="${prePhases[*]:-} unpackPhase patchPhase ${preConfigurePhases[*]:-} \
    configurePhase ${preBuildPhases[*]:-} buildPhase checkPhase \
    ${preInstallPhases[*]:-} installPhase ${preFixupPhases[*]:-} fixupPhase installCheckPhase \
    ${preDistPhases[*]:-} distPhase ${postPhases[*]:-}";

# test
#patchPhase="echo test error in patchPhase; false"

donePhases=()
missingPhases=($phases)
for curPhase in $phases; do
    # no. genericBuild does not "return 1" on error
    #phases="$curPhase" genericBuild || break
    echo
    echo "# running $curPhase"
    # FIXME this also traps suspend (Ctrl-Z)
    trap '
        echo "FIXME error in $curPhase"
        echo "done phases:" ${donePhases[@]}
        echo "missing phases:" ${missingPhases[@]}
        echo "hit Enter to close the nix-shell"
        read
    ' EXIT
    set -e # exit on error
    set -x # trace
    eval "${!curPhase:-$curPhase}"
    set +x
    set +e
    if [ "$curPhase" = unpackPhase ]; then
        [ -n "${sourceRoot:-}" ] && chmod +x "${sourceRoot}"
        cd "${sourceRoot:-.}"
    fi
    donePhases+=($curPhase)
    missingPhases=(${missingPhases[@]:1})
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question?

Comment: added more text from the nixos wiki. clearer now?

Comment: Sorry I'm a few years late, but yes this finally does make sense now though I think it's missing some context to highlight that these commands or phases relate to building a derivation. It would be useful to know that these commands are likely exactly the ones being run indirectly via `nix-build` and hence you get the full output with no truncation or aggregation.

Comment: `nix-build` can execute different build phases, for example in `python3.pkgs.buildPythonPackage`. the actual build phases are stored in the variable `$phases`, so in the nix-shell, see `echo $phases`. docs: [Building a stdenv package in nix-shell](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/stdenv/stdenv.chapter.md#building-a-stdenv-package-in-nix-shell-sec-building-stdenv-package-in-nix-shell), issues: [docs: fix nix-shell commands](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/7849), [docs: Building a stdenv package in nix-shell](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/216650)

Comment: Using this approach when running `buildPhase` results in: `no Makefile, doing nothing`. Other commands seem to fail with `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/nix/store/kk9irdv2ppca45fzwwz7422vsmbpgga1-HaskellNixCabalStarter-0.1.0.0’: Read-only file system`.

Comment: fixed my code to get the actual phases, including extra phases like `cmakeConfigurePhase`. the `Read-only file system` error is fixed by using different output paths. another problem is that `nix-build` runs the build script with `set -e` to stop on the first error, but this would exit the interactive bash shell... see also [nixos discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-build-phases-run-nix-build-phases-interactively/36090)

Comment: for the `chromium` package `eval "${unpackPhase:-unpackPhase}"` fails with `variable $src or $srcs should point to the source` but `phases="unpackPhase" genericBuild` works... so probably `genericBuild` is better as a generic phase runner

Comment: see also my [nix-build-debug](https://github.com/milahu/nix-build-debug) to stop on the first error

Answer (score 3):

There is a `--debug` option as well as a `--print-build-logs` option (on `nix build` but not `nix-build`) that can provide additional info.

Regarding the specific issue - it might be this bug: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2176

More information

https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-0.16/build/565033/download/1/manual/index.html#id494024

Comment: From the link: `At the beginning of each phase, the set of all shell variables is written to the file env-vars at the top-level build directory. This is useful for debugging: it allows you to recreate the environment in which a build was performed. For instance, if a build fails, then assuming you used the -K flag, you can go to the output directory and “switch” to the environment of the builder`

Comment: thank you! `--debug` is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `breakpointHook` to `nativeBuildInputs` of the failing derivation is also a powerful technique ― it allows you to connect with [`cntr`](https://github.com/Mic92/cntr) and explore the environment as it was at the point that the derivation's build failed.

[Thanks to jamesbrock on the NixOS Discourse,](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/debug-a-failed-derivation-with-breakpointhook-and-cntr/8669?u=r-k-b) the short of it is:

Add the `breakpointHook` package to the `nativeBuildInputs` of a `mkDerivation`.

```
nativeBuildInputs = [ breakpointHook ];
```

Install cntr

```
nix-env -i cntr
```

Run your Nix build command, and when it fails, the breakpointHook will output a message like this:

```
build failed in installPhase with exit code 1
To attach install cntr and run the following command as root:

   cntr attach -t command cntr-/nix/store/6vwxqrwq5h1fd3nw4mc61wgk7rppn2qw-jupyterlab-extended
```

So we run that command as **root**. The root user doesn’t have a `PATH` to the `cntr` command which we installed in our Nix profile, so give it the full path to our single-user-installed cntr.

```
sudo /home/$USER/.nix-profile/bin/cntr attach -t command cntr-/nix/store/6vwxqrwq5h1fd3nw4mc61wgk7rppn2qw-jupyterlab-extended
```

And now we’re in the sleeping Nix container.
Note that paths like `$out` and `$TMPDIR` are available at this stage along with your usual tools, however, they're under the current directory (`/var/lib/cntr`), instead of `/`.
(You can use them like `cd $(echo $out | cut -c2-)`.)

From here, run `cntr exec` to fully load the build environment.

```
/home/$USER/.nix-profile/bin/cntr exec
```

The `$TMPDIR` directory is where Nix has created the temporary directory for the build 10.

```
cd $TMPDIR
```

Now we are fully inside the context of the build, and any commands which we enter in the shell will be as if we had entered that command on a line in the phase (for example, `buildPhase`) of our derivation when the derivation failed.

---

Mentioned [here in the NixOS Discourse:](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/debugging-broken-builds/3138/5)

> I want to also add a few details regarding breakpointHook. It is a really powerful debug hook by [@Mic92](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/42371/files).
>
> It is enough to put pkgs.breakpointHook into your buildInputs to get it working. In the case of a failure there is an exact “connection” command printed out to the console. You can use this command (cntr) to attach a shell into the build environment. To use it you have to be able to run sudo along with cntr (so you should install cntr package before ;-)).
>
> You can find more interesting details in the @Mic92 NixCon presentation: [Jörg 'Mic92' Thalheim - About Nix sandboxes and breakpoints (NixCon 2018)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULqoCjANK-I)

Here's a link to the relevant section of the manual: https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#breakpointhook